# Difficulty dual booting with Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, kubuntu

So I've had kubuntu running on my lenovo laptop as the only operating system for most of the summer. Earlier this week, I decided to shrink the home partition in order to add a windows 7 partition.

After installing Windows 7, I was then stuck where I could boot into Windows 7, but could not boot into Kubuntu. I ended up using a kubuntu live usb in order to use the boot-repair tool, which let me regain access to GRUB, which now correctly lists Kubuntu and Windows 7 as the bootable operating systems, but it crashes any time I try to boot into windows. It is able to successfully boot into Kubuntu.

I ran the windows startup repair tool several times without success, as well as re-running the boot repair tool. Below is a link to the boot repair summary from the most recent attempt at boot-repair.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6146103/

Any suggestions as to how I could fix this without just wiping the drives and starting over?

Comment: Also, although the pasted summary says that the problem has been repaired, the problem has persisted.

Answer (score 0):

From Boot-Repair uncheck update all MBR, and check update MBR and choose to install the Windows work alike boot loader (syslinux) to sdb. And see if Windows will directly boot from sdb? If not then you need Windows repairs.

If Windows works then you may need to install grub to sdb, just to keep boot drive as hd0 or first drive. 
Sometimes BIOS/Windows does not correctly remap drives. Windows should work, but in some cases you have to install grub to Windows drive and boot from that drive. Something about Windows seeing boot drive as first drive.

Sometimes BIOS settings like AHCI may make a difference. Windows does need the AHCI drivers before changing if you have not installed them, otherwise it may not boot.